# Spring boot Maven Dependency Issue

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have two dependencies A and B. Inside B, I have multiple transitive dependencies BB1, BB2, BB3, BB4 etc. And inside of these transitive dependencies I have again dependency A with lower version which is causing problem.

```
A version 2.8
B version 2.4 > BB1 version 4.6 > A version 2.2
B version 2.4 > BB2 version 2.8 > A version 1.8
```

The project scans all nested dependencies and if it finds version of A lower than 2.8, it fails. B version 2.4 is the latest version. I tried exclusions inside B for A but didn't work. Is there anyway to increase version of A inside BB1 & BB2 explicitly? Any other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: "The project scans all nested dependencies and if it finds version of A lower than 2.8, it fails" - who does this at what point in time based on which information? If this is done e.g. based on the pom.xml you can't do much with exclusions.

Comment: It would be great to see the specific pom's. And your try to exclude the transitiv dependency

Answer (score 0):

Within the POM the A v2.8 would be the one considered (assuming it is declared explicitly in the POM), I think the issue is there is now cyclic dependency

Answer (score 0):

In this situation maven `dependencyMnagment` will resolve your issue.

It is good practice to use `dependencyManagement` to manage version of your artifact and version of transitive dependency (not all transitive are needed - only this with problem)

Another good tool is maven enforcer plugin, which can help to detect version conflicts.

From my experience excluding is not proper way to resolve versions conflict.

When you upgrade version of artifact, you can get another transitive dependency or one which was exclude is not need to be excluded.

And exclude dependency maybe required in runtime in your application in time when you don't expect.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/

https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html